# How to dynamically assign class methods from within class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, static-analysis

```py
import util
class C():
    save = util.save
setattr(C, 'load', util.load)
```

`C.save` is visible to the linter - but `C.load` isn't. There's thus some difference between assigning class methods from within the class itself, and from outside. Same deal for documentation builders; e.g. Sphinx won't acknowledge `:meth:C.load` - instead, need to do `:func:util.load`, which is misleading if `load` is meant to be `C`'s method. An IDE (Spyder) also fails to "go to" method via `self.load` code.

The end-goal is to make linter (+docs & IDE) recognize `load` as `C`'s method just like `C.save` is, but class method assignment needs to be dynamic ([context](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242152/210581)). Can this be accomplished?

---

**Note**: the purpose of dynamic assignment is to automatically pull methods from modules (e.g. `util`) instead of having to manually update `C` upon method addition / removal.

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer**: This solution does not work in all use cases, see comments. I leave it here, since it might still be useful under some circumstances.

I don't know about the linter and Sphinx, but an IDE like PyCharm will recognize the method if you declare it upfront using type hinting. In the code below, without the line `load: Callable[[], None]`, I get the warning 'Unresolved attribute reference', but with the line there are no warnings in the file. Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for more information about type hinting.

Notes:

- Even with the more general `load: Callable`, the type checker is satisfied.
- If you don't always declare a callable, a valid declaration is `load: Optional[Callable] = None`. This means that the default value is None. If you then call it without setting it, you will get an error, but you got that already anyway, that's unrelated to this typing.

p.s. I don't have your `utils`, so I defined some functions in the file itself.

```
from typing import Callable


def save():
    pass


def load():
    pass


class C:
    load: Callable[[], None]
    save = save


setattr(C, 'load', load)

C.load()
```

Comment: `load: ...` is still within `C`, which defeats the purpose of dynamic assignment; the idea is to automatically pull methods from modules instead of having to manually update `C` upon method addition / removal.

Comment: Ah, I see your use case now. Indeed, then this solution wouldn't work, you would still need to add something to class `C` every time you dynamically add a method.